# Bluemix Application Freeboard on Node-RED not Saving

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red, freeboard

I've created a [bluemix application](http://iotlabstart.mybluemix.net/freeboard/) that is using Node-RED to process my IoT sensors and I'm trying to use Freeboard as a dashboard. Only problem is the "Save Freeboard" button does nothing.

Any insight on how to fix this?

Comment: freeboard save button will call `saveDashboard()` it'll pop up a window to  download it. If your browser was not latest version will cause something error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where does Freeboard save it's data to? Is it backed by the filesystem or a database?

I'm not sure if Bluemix apps can save things to the "local" filesystem (and if it did it would not survive a app restart) and needs to use a database to store data.

Node-RED uses a CloudantDB instance to store flows and credentials.

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting your own freeboard, check the browser console for errors, by default what freeboard does is it tries download the JSON file with the layout to your computer when you click on "Save Freeboard".

Latest version will give you an option to save 'Minified' or 'Pretty' version of the JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

Probably due to you fixing it but it seems to be working alright. Just make sure you actually use the url you get when saving or it won't load the saved json.
http://iotlabstart.mybluemix.net/freeboard/#start-73622

Edit: and make sure you're actually clicking either "pretty" or "minified" after "save".